# Concerning ease of use Internal or Cycles for applying, and baking textures to Unity?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, unity

So okay I see many tutorials that are really GOOD, but to my surprise they are done with Internal even if the video is not old.

When I was comparing bake options I didn't see all the options I expected to see as I did see on the Internal bake options for example: Displacement I did not see this option for cycles. This option is important for baking out a combined height map.

From my current experience it appears to me that Cycles is more for the animation side of things, renders etc, whilst Blender Internal is still great for working with your various maps. I could be totally wrong, but as far as I can tell I should be using Internal for the time being to work with my game textures.

If anyone could shed some light on the situation I would really appreciate it.

TL;DR - Is Blender Internal better for game texturing and baking or is Cycles still the way to go, and I'm just not getting it yet.

Comment: I personally regard the internal as a technical resource: I use it for mattes and the like. It also does things like displacement baking quite well. However, if you want to bake anything that is even remotely related to light, use Cycles. (With the notable exception of baking AO. Cycles creates noise while the internal gives the same result noise-free.)

Comment: Well for simple combined baking of diffuse, specular, and normal maps from several materials as far as I can see the process is pretty straight forward on Internal. Would you consider my statement accurate?

Comment: Yes. It _is_ straightforward and, if for your use case it works, great. What I meant is that Cycles is made to produce as realistic results as possible. If you compare the maps from the two renderers, you will see that Cycles is more accurate with things like shadows. What I would personally do would be to make the specular and normal maps in the internal (though if you need a cage, only Cycles can do one afaik., not sure.) as they are faster and noise-free. However I would do the diffuse in cycles as it is raytraced and more realistic. This is only my oppinion. Do whatever best works for you.